# how to open .indd file in javascript in browser?

Tags: javascript, acrobat, adobe-indesign

indd file extension which has got lot of animation as well.how can i open .indd file in the brower. If i convert .indd file to pdf, is it able to show the animation same in .indd original file?

Answer (score 0):

InDesign .indd files are a proprietary format owned by Adobe. You aren't going to be able to use javascript to open or edit them. I found [this link](http://indesignsecrets.com/how-to-get-animations-to-work-in-pdf-working-title.php) on how to preserve animations when exporting InDesign files, that might be more of what you're looking for. Note that it says that animations do *not* carry over into .pdf format.

Comment: actually i found https://forums.adobe.com/message/6122200#6122200 this link .but i couldn't figure out what app.open comes from @jaredsk